# understanding the grad of constant vector in a vector equation

Tags: vectors

I have a following equation:
$$
\vec{K}=(\vec{n} \times i\vec{B}) G+\vec{B}\times\nabla G
$$
where $$ \vec n=(1,0,0) \\
\vec{K}=(K_x, K_y, K_z)\\ \vec B=(B_x,B_y, B_z)\\ G=\frac {exp(-i|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|)} {|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|}\\ \vec r_{1,2} = (r_{x_{1,2}}, r_{y_{1,2}})
$$
My goal is to split this equation in 3 individual component equations for: $K_x$, $K_y$ and $K_z$.

The only part that troubles me is $\nabla G$ (which by the way is the same as $grad(G)$). When I use this formula in my numerical calculations, my $\vec r_1, \vec r_2$ are known (these are simple vectors in a 2D coordinate system). So basically the terms $r_x, r_y$ are known scalars and the term $grad(G)$ results in [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=grad%28exp%28%20-i%20*magnitude%20%28x,y%29%20%29%20%2Fmagnitude%20%28x,y%29%29).

If I understand it right, $\vec grad(G)$ becomes $0$ in any case since both $r_x, r_y$ components are scalars and in the result, a derivative is applied to $r_x$ and $r_y$ component - and a derivative of a constant scalar is $0$. 
If so, then the whole equation becomes very simple and I get $$
K_x = 0\\ K_y = -iB_zG\\  K_z=iB_yG
$$

Do I see it right or is there a mistake that I can't recognize?

Comment: Is this an exercise in Chapter 9 of Jackson E&M?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You might want to edit your title to make it more informative. As it stands, it describes every question on the site.

Comment: no this is not an exercise :) - but the formula is similar to kirchoff-Integral from Jackson E&M. Thanks - I have edited the title